# ReactJS element is not displaying on the website I'm working on

Tags: reactjs

I've to work on a Joomla website, and I've added a ReactJS element to the site, but it's just not displaying. Everything looks fine, but nothing shows up.
I've added the babel and the React libraries to the site.

This is the html element:

```
    <div id="contact_button_container">&nbsp;</div>
```

This is the ReactJS:

```
    'use strict';

    const buttonElement = React.createElement;

    class ContactButton extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { revealed: false };
      }

      render() {
        if (this.state.revealed) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <a className="btn btn-primary" href="/contact-us">Less then 10 steps</a>
                    <a className="btn btn-primary" href="/contact-us">More then 10 steps</a>
                    <a className="btn btn-primary" href="/contact-us">More then 15 steps</a>
                </div>
            )
        }

        return buttonElement(
          <button onClick={() => this.setState({ revealed: true })}>
            Contact by Clicking here
          </button>
        );
      }
    }

    const domContainer = document.querySelector('#contact_button_container');
    ReactDOM.render(e(ContactButton), domContainer);
```

It would be really great if someone can explain me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using react, reactDOM and babel, you can directly make use of JSX instead of React.createElement. Another problem with the code is reference to `e`. `e` is not defined in your case. Also the syntax for defining element using React.createElement() is wrong.

```
  <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Load our React component. -->
    <script type="text/babel">
      class ContactButton extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = { revealed: false };
        }

        render() {
          if (this.state.revealed) {
            return (
              <div>
                <a className="btn btn-primary" href="/contact-us">
                  Less then 10 steps
                </a>
                <a className="btn btn-primary" href="/contact-us">
                  More then 10 steps
                </a>
                <a className="btn btn-primary" href="/contact-us">
                  More then 15 steps
                </a>
              </div>
            );
          }

          return (
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ revealed: true })}>
              Contact by Clicking here
            </button>
          );
        }
      }

      const domContainer = document.querySelector("#contact_button_container");
      ReactDOM.render(<ContactButton />, domContainer);
```

The above code will do.